# rebuild_tree performance issue - Takes too much time

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, mptt

I'm using flask `SQLAlchemy-MPTT` https://sqlalchemy-mptt.readthedocs.io/tut_flask.html in one of my project as the data is hierarchical in nature, And the `rebuild_tree` operation in `SQLAlchemy-MPTT` (Modified Preorder Tree Traversal) is responsible for updating the tree structure based on the parent-child relationships in the database.

While testing locally with up to 10 trees it is no performance issue at all, but I'm concerned when there are 100s of trees in my db, and I'm calling the rebuild command (which will rebuild all 100s of trees), this might be a significant performance issue.

Actual Behavior:
The `rebuild_tree` operation is taking an unreasonably long time, especially noticeable when dealing with larger datasets, adversely affecting the overall performance of the library.

Expected Behavior:
The `rebuild_tree` operation should complete within a reasonable time frame, even as the size of the dataset grows.

Anybody out there who has experience with using the rebuild command?

This is how I'm calling rebuild_tree to update the left, right of a tree

MyModel.rebuild_tree(db.session, root_.tree_id)  # rebuild lft, rgt value automatically
db.session.commit()

but for larger datasets it's taking too much of time,

Comment: I think that is considered a drawback of MPTT.  Which is why you do not want many changes to take place.

Comment: Can you turn `echo=True` for the engine?  Then I think you will see that a lot of updates are being generated. I haven't used this tool but looking at the source code, if you call rebuild tree then it has to update each node in that tree.

Comment: Yes, I saw many update queries are being triggered while executing `rebuild_tree`. and this operation is expensive because it has to start from root to all of it's leaf nodes. Is there any hack that we could do to make it faster? like batch `rebuild_tree`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by batch but depending on your app you could run the rebuild in a cron-like batch job.  As long as your app didn't depend on the accuracy of the reads.

Comment: Do you really need MPTT though?  It is a very specific pattern that is hard to maintain and hard to optimize around.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @IanWilson, I'll try to keep things simple by utilizing the `parent_id` information only and avoiding the use of `rebuild_tree`.